# Mail attachement problem

Tags: macos, mac, email, attachments

I have a problem with mail application.

Using it from OS X when I send mail including an attachment like image, pdf or any oder document and if my recipient reads the mail on windows devices, they do not see the text of my mail and a signature, but instead the whole text and signature of the email all are processed as an attachment.

LIKE THIS... [image: I send this]

[image: they see this]

MacBook Air (13-inch, Early 2015), iOS 9.1, OS X Yosemite version 10.10.5

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different. We can help with translation and grammar, but we need more details. What specifically is in the signature and what are you attaching? What one OS is composing the mail? Are you sending html, plain text, rtf in the body? What's in the attachment? On OS X you can just use the format menu to make a mail plain text. Is that what you need?

Comment: Best guess would be Windows Outlook email, which behaves differently to pretty much everything else. MS going it alone again. Outlook seems to only be able to inline one attachment; as soon as there are two, it just lumps them all together at the end.

Comment: Looks pretty clear to me. The Windows email contains an attached txt file that I'd assume contains the text of their signature.

Answer (score -1):

You can try [Universal Mailer Plugin](http://universalmailer.github.io/UniversalMailer/) to Apple Mail.
It has options to keep signature text formatting as well as how to treat images in the message.